# Descending order with if-else and NOT use Logical operators Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Given **three numbers**, print them in descending order using the **if...else** statements described above. You are **not allowed to use any logical operator** to solve this problem, but you are welcome to **use comparison operators.**

```
    var a = 3;
    var b = 2;
    var c = 1;

    if(a<b<c){
      console.log(c,b,a)
    }
    if(b<c<a){
      console.log(b,c,a)
    }
    if(c<a<b){
      console.log(c,a,b)
    }
// I understand this is wrong as when I do a<b<c
// First it compares a<b = true(1) or false(0) and remaining compares to c
// the answer in boolean 
// How do I approach this problem?
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Hi @MarkMeyer 
I need to get descending order of any 3 numbers with out using Logical Operators or Advanced Js operations like sort.

Comment: Yes, that's clear, but it doesn't look like you have a question about something you've tried to do. What aspect of this problem don't you understand? What have you tried?

Comment: As step 1 : I tried to check the possibility of comparing 3 vars with each other that's 3! =6 ways
And then I don't get how I get the descending order with no logical operators

Comment: Instead of, `a<b<c`, you probably want to do `a<b && b<c`.

Comment: @David784 Thanks for your response. 
Is there any other way to achieve it without using Logical operators?

Comment: You can use nested if statements, if that's permitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting to only use if statements, here is a solution.  I'm sure this could be shortened in some way

```
if (c > b) {
    if (b > a) {
        return console.log(c, b, a)
    }
    if (c > a) {
        return console.log(c, a, b)
    }
    return console.log(a, c, b)
}

if (b > a) {
    if (a > c) {
        return console.log(b, a, c)
    }
    if (b > a) {
        return console.log(b, c, a)
    }
    return console.log(c, b, a)
}

if (a > c) {
    if (c > b) {
        return console.log(a, c, b)
    }
    if (a > b) {
        return console.log(a, b, c)
    }
    return console.log(b, a, c)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = 3;
var b = 2;
var c = 1;

if(a<b){
    if(b<c){
        console.log(c,b,a);
    }else if(a < c){
        console.log(b,c,a);
    }else{
        console.log(b,a,c);
    }
}else if(c<a){
    if(b<c){
        console.log(a,c,b);
    }else{
        console.log(a,b,c);
    }
}else{
    console.log(c,a,b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var a = 5
    var b = 2
    var c = 3

    if(a<b){
      if(c<a){
        console.log(b,a,c);
      } else if(b<c){
        console.log(c,b,a);
    }else{
        console.log(b,c,a);
      } 
      } else if(a<c){
        console.log(c,a,b);
      } else if(c<b){
        console.log(a,b,c);
      }

    else{
        console.log(a,c,b);
      }
```

//Understood it better knowing the concept of Bubble, Insertion sorting.